# Where are docker images gcloud should build from

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, cloud, containers, google-cloud-platform

I've read [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/deploying-docker-containers) that I can use the `gcloud` sdk to create an instance from a container image. Here's how they say to do for nginx.

```
gcloud alpha compute instances create-from-container nginx-vm \
    --docker-image=gcr.io/google-containers/nginx:latest \
    --port-mappings=80:80:TCP
```

I'd like to be able to do this with a node image i've made. I can run it locally using `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d myusername/node-web-app`, but I don't understand where the image is. Is the idea that I can just scp the image to the VM I have running on cloud compute, and then use a snippet like the one above? How can I find this image in order to do that? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792709/1252748) indicates that they are located at */Users/MyUserName/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2*, The listing there doesn't look very promising:

```
- .
- ..
- Docker.qcow2
- console-ring
- console-ring.0
- console-ring.1
- console-ring.2
- console-ring.3
- console-ring.4
- console-ring.5
- hypervisor.pid
- lock
- log
- mac.0
- nic1.uuid
- pid
- syslog
- tty -> /dev/ttys000
```

#### Is this the correct way to build from a container on Cloud Compute? If so, where are the images from which the app should be built from?

Answer (score 6):

> I don't understand where the image is.

It is in your local docker repository (which could be served by [a local registry service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34004418/6309), but you don't need one here)

> Is the idea that I can just scp the image to the VM I have running on cloud compute the "`gcloud alpha compute instances create-from-container`" command.

Not exactly: the idea is that you can push your local image to a google cloud registry service: see "[GCP: Pushing and Pulling Images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling)"

Once the image is pushed, you can use the "`gcloud alpha compute instances create-from-container`" command.

So you don't need to know *exactly* where your image is stored locally.
You only need to:

> - Tag your image by running the following Docker command:
>
>   ```
>     docker tag [IMAGE] [HOSTNAME]/[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
>   ```
> - push the image to Container Registry by running the following command:
>
>   ```
>     gcloud docker -- push [HOSTNAME]/[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
>   ```