# Does "The push refers to a repository" actually mean "…refers to a registry"?

Tags: docker

I'm reasonably familiar with Docker at this point but as these things go I'm no expert.

When I do a `docker push`, I always (?) get what looks like an informative message: `The push refers to a repository [registry.bigco.com/foobar/blatz]`.

Empirically it looks like if I use the command line tools, I will get this message if I do:

```
docker push registry.bigco.com/foobar/blatz
```

(In this case if I've got several `registry.bigco.com/foobar/blatz` images tagged with "colon tags" (e.g. `registry.bigco.com/foobar/blatz:development`) lying around in my local Docker environment, then this operation will `push` them all.)

I'll also get it if I do:

```
docker push registry.bigco.com/foobar/blatz:development
```

…i.e. a specific tag.  That surprises me, because I figured the presence of the `development` "colon tag" picks out a very specific image I'm pushing, and not the contents of my local Docker environment, and, indeed, that's all that gets `push`ed.  That is, if I'm understanding what "repository" means in this case, I'm certainly trying *not* to refer to a repository at all!

What *is* this message trying to tell me?  Is it trying, actually, to tell me that my `push` operation is referring to a *registry*, i.e. that the `registry.bigco.com` part is being treated as not a username on Docker Hub?  Is this a gigantic typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Docker registry and repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004076/difference-between-docker-registry-and-repository)

Comment: Hi; thanks; I don't think this is a duplicate.  For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904365/208288) implies that if I push an _image_, indeed I should not be told that I am pushing a _repository_. So I am still trying to understand the notification message described above.

Comment: OK, the message might be a bit misleading, I think changing it to "refers to *the* repository" might make it more clear. If you have a look at [the source](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/distribution/push.go#L72), you will see that the message is always printed, whether you are pushing a single image or a whole repository. It merely states the source of the images that are being pushed.

Comment: Thank you; so in effect, a push can refer to nothing else, right? As in, this message is entirely superfluous?

Comment: Yes, a push will always refer to a repository. The message is not superfluous, however, as it tells the user how Docker has resolved the given arguments. Try `docker push lalala` and you will see which repository docker assumes: "The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/lalala]"

Comment: OK, so to sum up: even though I think I am pushing an _image_, I am always pushing a _repository_, even when I am pushing `some/thing:likethis`?  And the message is telling me, superfluously, that I am pushing a repository—it's the only thing I can push—but, helpfully, that is named thus-and-such…?  Sorry for these thick-headed questions; I like my terminology to be unambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was a bit confusing. You _can_ push a single image. Taking the previous example, `docker push lalala:mytag` will only push the image with this specific tag. However, one might think that the full name of the lalala repository is (for example) myregistry.io/user1/lalala. So, just to be sure, docker will print the *full* repository name it will actually use: docker.io/library/lalala. As ":mytag" was specified, *only* this tag will be pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution to this. Sometimes the docker.sock is not in the correct place and the correction to this was running a sudo su in the command line to perform the commands as shell root and it bypassed it. You can likely also change this by adding it to the root directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Registry operations are scoped to a repository (a path on the registry), including all of the blob and manifest push and pull requests. So the output tells you to which repository the current push command is applying. If you try to later pull one of the digests from another repository on the same registry, unless it was separately pushed to that repository, the command would be expected to fail.

```bash
$ docker push ${repo1}
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [${repo1}]
62a81b88f141: Pushed
425c3a844b1d: Pushed
2a5659e7e861: Pushed
ef86d6172743: Pushed
bd1b6591d9e4: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9d5a992e1125 size: 1358

$ docker pull ${repo2}@sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9d5a992e1125
Error response from daemon: unknown: {"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"manifest unknown to registry","detail":"tag or digest was not found in repository"}]}

$ docker pull ${repo1}@sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9
d5a992e1125
${repo1}@sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9d5a992e1125: Pulling from ${repo1}
Digest: sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9d5a992e1125
Status: Image is up to date for ${repo1}@sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9d5a992e1125
${repo1}@sha256:5bec5a1ffeca7ab4a34d557c24ea654441c4d60cd2b7b98f97af9d5a992e1125
```