# docker build and push pipeline tasks tagging the image with Asterisks and then not able to find them

Tags: devops, acr

We are trying to build and push a docker image to Azure Container Registry. If we do build and push in the same step, everything works fine. But we are trying to build once and promote to all environments from that build. So, we need to build in the build stage and push in the deploy stage.

Following is the code for build step

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build API Docker Image
  inputs:
   containerRegistryType: Azure Container Registry
   repository: $(acrHostName)/$(imageName)
   azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscription)
   azureContainerRegistry: $(acrHostName)
   tags: |
      $(tag)
```

If I run the above code, docker adds *** in front of the image name and then it can't find the image by the tag I provide.

I have read the documentation like million times, it has something to do with hiding secret information but I am clueless as to why it can't find it.

[pipeline run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqUjJ.jpg)

In the picture, you can see that the image is available under the repository but not found by the docker.

imageName= onlinecalcs

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

Most likely you've defined connection to your Azure Container Registry (ACR) as a [Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure Pipelines. Service Connections are treated as secrets for security reasons, and their values are masked in logs with three asterisks (***).

**Explanation**

If a pipeline uses Microsoft-hosted agents (in self-hosted agents pathes might be different) you can find similar lines of logs in the correspondent Docker build task output:

> /usr/bin/docker build --label myLabelKey="myLabelValue" --tag ***/my-repository:my-tag

In the log, the `***` represents the ACR name that you've defined in your Service Connection. To get the correct full image reference, replace `***` with your ACR name. For example, if your ACR name is `mycustomacr.azurecr.io`, the full image reference should be `mycustomacr.azurecr.io/my-repository:my-tag`. Using just `my-repository:my-tag` won't work correctly if you've already built the image with the registry prefix.

**Terminology Clarification**

It's important to note that in Docker, the term "*repository*" refers to a collection of images, not the registry where these images are stored. This distinction can sometimes lead to confusion. You can find more information about this in [Difference between Docker registry and repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004076/difference-between-docker-registry-and-repository).

Therefore, having your image prefixed with `mycustomacr.azurecr.io` doesn't necessarily mean the image is coming from or belongs to a remote image registry; it's only a local image until you push it to the dedicated registry storage.