# what about the docker image if a container is crashed?

Tags: docker, crash, containers

For my opinion, a container is a running instance of image. What if the container is crashed, for example run `sudo rm -f /` delete all the stuffs, is the docker image still OK?

Comment: An instance of an image is a container and you can have some instances of the same image so the Image still OK. Images are immutables.

Comment: Although it partly depends on where the hypothetical `rm -rf /` happens -- if the entire host is wiped, you will lose both the containers and the images. However, if the images have been pushed to a remote repo and/or you have the Dockerfiles, they should be easily recreated _if_ they have been treated as immutable (which isn't always the case). So your best plan is to have a repo with a Dockerfile and any (up-to-date) support files available. If the container crashes, you may lose any uncommitted changes, but you shouldn't set up your containers/images that way in any case.

Answer (score 3):

No effect for image in both cases.
Look if you create new container via [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/), virtually new layer

[image]

> When you create a new container, you add a new, thin, writable layer on top of the underlying stack. This layer is often called the “container layer”. All changes made to the running container - such as writing new files, modifying existing files, and deleting files - are written to this thin writable container layer. The diagram below shows a container based on the Ubuntu 15.04 image.
>   [src](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)

This stackopverflow discussion may be helpful as well:
[Docker image vs container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/docker-image-vs-container)