# How to run a CMD and open Bash when running a docker container?

Tags: django, bash, docker, dockerfile

I am having a rough time trying to figure this out.

So I have a dockerfile based on an Ubuntu image.  At the end of my dockerfile I have:

```
CMD django-admin startproject $PROJECTNAME
```

I was told in a previous post that the base Ubuntu image has a CMD to run /bin/bash so my command is actually overwriting this (not sure if this is relevant or not).

The problem I'm encountering is if I run:

```
docker run -i -t <containerid>
```

Nothing happens..  docker ps shows no containers are running

But if I run:

```
docker run -i -t <containerid> /bin/bash
```

The container starts running, I am in the shell, and docker ps shows that this container is running.  Everything works as expected, but my django project is not there and my understanding is that running /bin/bash overrides the CMD in the dockerfile, which means django-admin startproject never gets run.

From inside the container, I can run django-admin startproject $projectname and  it creates the project with no issues, which tells me django and all its dependencies are installed, and my environment variables are being registered.

However, I still suspect that there maybe is an issue with my CMD in my dockerfile and I don't know where to go from here.

With my provided dockerfile, if I do not run the container with /bin/bash, the container will not run.

Output of docker images:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
<none>              <none>              cbec557d6362        About a minute ago   579 MB
<none>              <none>              6919c19b159a        16 hours ago
```

docker run:

```
docker run -i -t cbec557d6362
```

Comment: Two related questions, did you build an image using your Dockerfile? Do you understand the difference between an [image and a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/docker-image-vs-container)?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: Could you include the output of `docker images` and the exact `docker run` command? Just want to confirm you are launching the correct image.

Comment: Okay I included it.

Comment: Are you able to join [this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76919/docker)? That may be faster than comments

Answer (score 2):

I commented on the original issue but for whatever reason there is a new one now. When you run `/bin/bash` that *becomes* the command run in that container, a bash shell. You can do whatever you want in the container (like create a Django project) but when you exit that shell the container still stop (as containers stop when the PID 1 process, in this case, `/bin/bash`) exits.

My suspicion (I don't know Django super well) is that the command `django-admin startproject $PROJECTNAME` is being run, *completes successfully* then exits. It's PID 1, so the container stops. This is why `docker ps` shows nothing.

My suggestion would be to instead use `RUN django-admin startproject $PROJECTNAME` in your Dockerfile followed by `CMD /bin/bash`.

Build the container then run it and you should be in a bash shell, check if your project is created.