# Is "Docker" an implementation of "Container"?

Tags: docker, implementation

I'm trying to learn Docker and came to know of the term Container. I am bit confused, in most of the online materials which I referred to (understand Docker), the term "Container" appears somewhere.

What is the difference between Docker and Container and is Docker one of the implementations of Container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker image vs container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/docker-image-vs-container)

Comment: @rigsby Not a duplicate. This is a good question. Difficult to answer. In some sense Docker was one implementation of a container technology. Docker has evolved since this question was asked and now it is more like a brand name on several technologies and tools. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Container` is essentially a package(with an embedded application) that can be run anywhere. A `Container` allows a developer to package an application with all of the dependencies it needs, and ship it as one package.

At a lower level, a `Container` is an operating system level virtualization method for running multiple isolated Linux systems (containers) on a control host using a single Linux kernel. LXC(Linux Containers) combines the kernel's cgroups and support for isolated namespaces to provide an isolated environment for applications.

`Docker` is a tool that was designed to make it much easier to create, deploy, and run applications in `containers`, rather than using LXC(Linux Containers) directly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Upon further reading online, does a container have a bare minimum OS as well? And that bare minimum OS utilises the other services from host os? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Docker has changed over the years. Now Docker is a brand-name on many technologies. Docker contains many tools, it isn't one tool anymore. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))

Answer (score 0):

All `docker`'s are containers not all containers are `docker`.

`docker` is a strict subset of `containers`.

A `container` is a generic term, like you said, `docker` is a particular implementation of a container system.

Comment: Can you expand your answer, in essence what is a Container?

Comment: a container provides an additional layer of abstraction and automation of operating-system-level virtualization. You configure this container and create a snapshot of a system that you might want and it can be stored as a static entity. Often for scalability, reliability, predictability of a runtime.

Comment: also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/docker-image-vs-container) may provide some nice tidbits :)