# Making changes to Smart Contract in Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If I want to make some changes in my Smart Contract , I have to delete the docker image of my running application. Which results in complete loss of data.
How can I push the changes in my smart contract  such that I don't have to delete the docker image of the current application ???????????

Comment: I think you mean container, not image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/docker-image-vs-container

Comment: I mean image only .
when I run my application for the first time a docker image is created which can checked by running this command in a terminal
$ docker images 
It shows all the docker images among which there is an image of my application.

Answer (score 0):

peer chaincode upgrade ...

peer chaincode upgrade --help

Full details in the docs.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/chaincode4noah.html

It's almost identical to peer chaincode instantiate ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your current version of the chaincode into a new one which will contain required changes, the steps are as following:

1. Installing new chaincode with updated version on all peers involved

   `peer chaincode install -o localhost:7050 -n myCC -v 2.0 -p github.com/chaincode/mycc`
2. Upgrade chaincode to newer version

   `peer chaincode upgrade -o localhost:7050 -n myCC -v 2.0 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":[]}'`