# Docker image can't be deleted, "no such image"

Tags: docker

Okay, so I'm brand new to Docker and doing some tutorials and I want to delete the `nginx` and `mongo` images:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx                latest              be1f31be9a87        12 days ago         109MB
mongo                3.4                 598e8cf490a6        12 days ago         361MB
```

So I start with `nginx`:

```
$ docker image rm nginx
Untagged: nginx:latest
Untagged: nginx@sha256:9ad0746d8f2ea6df3a17ba89eca40b48c47066dfab55a75e08e2b70fc80d929e
Deleted: sha256:be1f31be9a87cc4b8668e6f0fee4efd2b43e5d4f7734c75ac49432175aaa6ef9
Deleted: sha256:7609c40a03b852382a43d79231d9d4ca7661cd1ac9edcb46f78a44fff4ed59ca
Deleted: sha256:a2b6968c4326640dd5e9e22ddf6cebb61ba1a4b79a4ac8d194f93000c5a4c3e2
Deleted: sha256:8b15606a9e3e430cb7ba739fde2fbb3734a19f8a59a825ffa877f9be49059817
```

Has it gone?

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mongo                3.4                 598e8cf490a6        12 days ago         361MB
```

So far so good. Now for `mongo`:

```
$ docker image rm mongo
Error: No such image: mongo
```

Why didn't this work?

In the end I found that `docker image rm 598e8cf490a6` did remove the `mongo` image, but I still don't understand why this didn't work.

- What is that first column, `REPOSITORY`? Is that the image name, or something else?
- If it is the image name, then why can't I delete the `mongo` image using `docker image rm mongo`?
- If it isn't the image name, then

  1. What is it?
  2. Why does `docker image ls` show it instead of the image name?
  3. How do I get the actual image name? And specifically what is it? I also tried `docker image rm mongodb` and `docker image rm mongo-db` with no success.

Comment: `docker image rm mongo:3.4`?

Answer (score 7):

> As explained in the following thread -
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/23736802/10488199

An instance of an image is called a container. You have an image, which is a set of layers as you describe. If you start this image, you have a running container of this image. You can have many running containers of the same image.
You can see all your images with docker images whereas you can see your running containers with docker ps (and you can see all containers with docker ps -a).
So a running instance of an image is a container.

To view the list of running container instances

use -> `$ docker ps`

To view the list of all the container instances

use -> `$ docker ps -a`

To view, the list of images pulled

use -> `$ docker images`

To remove a container instance (if the container is running)

use -> `$ docker kill <container id/container name>`
use -> `$ docker rm <container id/container name>`

or force it to stop and remove it by

use -> `$ docker rm -f <container id/container name>`

To remove a container instance (if the container is not running)

use -> `$ docker rm <container id/container name>`

To remove an image

use -> `$ docker rmi <REPOSITORY:tag/IMAGEID>`

or

use -> `$ docker image rm <REPOSITORY:tag/IMAGEID>`

**NOTE: If the REPOSITORY being removed has the latest tag, there is no need of mentioning it. If there is a tag, it should be mentioned.**

In your case

use -> `$ docker images rm mongo:3.4`

Comment: Nope.  Still not working for me.  It still says "No Such Image", when I can see it staring me in the face in the ls command.  Even restarted docker.  Portainer also can't remove it.  Aha... maybe its because it was created with a much older version of Docker ??

Comment: Check the details of docker image using ```docker image inspect <imagename>```. Try docker image prune for unused image.

Answer (score 0):

The "name" of an image in docker is a combination of repository and ID - this is what is shown in `docker image ls`.

You will find the repository name on the docker hub as well, e.g.: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

If you provide only the name of the repository - in this case "mongo", docker assumes that you would like to delete the image which is tagged "latest" for this repository.
Now since in your example you have only one image tagged "mongo:3.4", but no image called "mongo:latest", this doesn't work.

You can force to remove all images from one repository by adding the `-f` flag, e.g. `docker rmi -f mongo`.

See the official documentation for more information and examples: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/#parent-command

Comment: "docker assumes that you would like to delete the image which is tagged 'latest'" Gee, if only `docker` itself had bothered to explain this! "No such image: `mongo:latest`", maybe?

Comment: What's the difference between `docker rmi` and `docker image rm`?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, ``docker rmi`` is just a short form for ``docker image rm``. You can see in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/) that ``docker image rm`` supports the ``-f`` flag as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy, try

```
$ docker image rm your-proxy:port/image-name
```

or

```
$ docker image rm -f your-proxy:port/image-name
```