# How to stop Image in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I tried ctrl + c, ctrl + d, ctrl + qp
But, I am still unable to terminate the running Image or get out of the terminal

[image: Terminal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only stop containers, but not images. Explained [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/what-is-the-difference-between-a-docker-image-and-a-container)

To stop the container:

- Get the container id using `docker ps`
- Stop it using `docker container stop <id>`

Eventually you want to kill it using `docker kill <id>` (kill also like in send a signal)