# Docker: Docker run does not report error but docker file has errors, how to view them?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Here is my docker file a very simple docker file

```
FROM node:19-alpine

COPY package.json /app/

COPY src /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

RUN ls

CMD [ "node", "src/index.js" ] //it has error, it should be index.js
```

When I try to execute `docker build` command it shoes the container id however `docker ps` does not show any containers, which means container was not launched successfully and there is problem with docker file.

the error is reported if I try to run container from docker client GUI.

**How to view the errors from command line if docker file has a problem and it wasn't reported by docker build command?**

Comment: You are probably confusing Docker image and container. `docker build` will build an image, and you need to use the `docker run` command to launch container from the specified image:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/what-is-the-difference-between-a-docker-image-and-a-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker ps` only shows running containers.

If you do `docker ps -a` you should see the container and that it has the 'exited' status.

You can then do `docker logs <container name>` to see any error messages.

Comment: Out of all the comments and answers you understood what I wanted to achieve. Thank you it worked